# Uncaught ReferenceError: Trello is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, trello

I try to integrate the Trello API (a dashboard API with cards) to my website.
Unfortunately, not work.

The goal is to authentificate to display the Trello content for a user.
I have this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Trello is not defined.

I think it's a  problem but i can not find. Can you help me please ?

i used smarty template on PHP.
here is the code for the .tpl :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=mykey"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    console.log(jQuery.Trello);
    var authenticationSuccess = function() { console.log('Successful authentication'); };
    var authenticationFailure = function() { console.log('Failed authentication'); };

    jQuery.Trello.authorize({
      type: 'redirect',
      name: 'WAL',
      scope: {
      read: 'true',
      write: 'true' },
      expiration: 'never',
      success: authenticationSuccess,
      error: authenticationFailure
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: i guess `jquery.Trello.authorize` instead of `Trello.authorize`

Comment: Does your `console.log(jQuery.Trello);` show an object in the console or `undefined`, because if shows an object then it should be `jQuery.Trello.authorize`.

Comment: `Trello is not defined` - yes, if the error states that Trello is not defined, then you can bet the problem is that Trello is not defined ...

Comment: +2? Really? This is probably a typo, considering the difference between the `log` call and the `Trello.` call.

Comment: i've already try jQuery.Trello.authorize and it's not work too. The console show "undefined"

Comment: just change console.log(jQuery.Trello); on console.log(Trello);

Comment: i just tested : Trello is not defined. Same :(

Comment: Your code works perfectly in fiddle, so it looks like is something related to your installation. Can be any firewall/proxy blocking access to api.trello.com? Internet connection is working?

Comment: I don't understand ... not works on my page but 
it seems to work on the browser console (chrome):                                
Trello (on brower console)
{version: ƒ, key: ƒ, setKey: ƒ, token: ƒ, setToken: ƒ, …}

Comment: but i have this too : Uncaught ReferenceError: Trello is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.7.js:614), <anonymous>:46:5)
    at fire (jquery-1.7.js:1064)
    at Object.add (jquery-1.7.js:1099)
    at init.ready (jquery-1.7.js:282)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.7.js:614), <anonymous>:4:20)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery-1.7.js:614
    at Function.globalEval (jquery-1.7.js:615)
    at HTMLScriptElement.evalScript (jquery-1.7.js:6487)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.7.js:660)

Comment: A. Iglesias : yes all is working fine. Actually i have some widgets on my home page (some boxes with differents contents). If i try to authorize Trello on an other page dedicated to Trello it's work, but in my widget at home page it's not work